# Tool to monitor pi performance/resources via website?

Tags: cpu, monitoring

Is there a tool for the raspery pi to monitor cpu, ram, storage, resources ... sys health etc. via a web gui?

Comment: Presuming you are using a GNU/Linux distro (eg. Raspbian), you should be able to find **a ton** of stuff -- winner for snazziest looking in my 2 minute prowl searching "linux web based monitoring" is https://cockpit-project.org/ And `apt search cockpit` reveals it is in the Raspbian repos.  Maybe overkill tho...

Comment: I use https://github.com/XavierBerger/RPi-Monitor which provides most of the above. (It doesn't know about Pi4)